# Android Proguard - Reflection java.lang.reflect call not working

Tags: java, android, reflection, proguard

I'm using the follow method to force stacked tabs on my Android ActionBar.

When I come to use proguard, the Class manipulation no longer works work. No error messages are received, I just don't get the stacked tab ActionBar.

This is what I have in my proguard rules. Is there anything clear I'm missing?

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class java.lang.reflect.** { *; }
-keep class com.company.myapplication1.SetStackedTabs.** { *; }
```

_

```
public static void SetStackedTabs(Object inActionBar, final boolean inHasEmbeddedTabs){
    // get the ActionBar class
    Class<?> actionBarClass = inActionBar.getClass();

    // if it is a Jelly Bean implementation (ActionBarImplJB), get the super class (ActionBarImplICS)
    if ("android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB".equals(actionBarClass.getName()))
    {
        actionBarClass = actionBarClass.getSuperclass();
    }

    // if Android 4.3 >
    if ("android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJBMR2".equals(actionBarClass.getName())){
        actionBarClass = actionBarClass.getSuperclass().getSuperclass();
    }

    try
    {
        // try to get the mActionBar field, because the current ActionBar is probably just a wrapper Class
        // if this fails, no worries, this will be an instance of the native ActionBar class or from the ActionBarImplBase class
        final Field actionBarField = actionBarClass.getDeclaredField("mActionBar");
        actionBarField.setAccessible(true);
        inActionBar = actionBarField.get(inActionBar);
        actionBarClass = inActionBar.getClass();
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {}
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {}

    try
    {
        // now call the method setHasEmbeddedTabs, this will put the tabs inside the ActionBar
        // if this fails, you're on you own <img class="wp-smiley" alt=";-)" src="http://www.blogc.at/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_wink.gif">
        final Method method = actionBarClass.getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", new Class[] { Boolean.TYPE });
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(inActionBar, new Object[]{ inHasEmbeddedTabs });
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e)        {}
    catch (InvocationTargetException e) {}
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {}
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it.

I had to enter this line into the ProGuard configuration.

```
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

Comment: Proguard obfuscate your code. Depending on proguard configuration class, method, field, local variable are renamed. So here you check if a class name is equal to an other one but proguard changed it for something like A.class. Using -keep class proguard won't change class matching the given pattern.

Comment: at which position did you add -keep class android.support.v7.** { *; } ? I'm facing the same problem.